# High CPU load makes receiving NFQUEUE packets go faster

Tags: linux, netfilter

I use [libmnl](https://www.netfilter.org/projects/libmnl/index.html) to receive packets directed to user-space with the iptables "-j NFQUEUE". It works well. Here is the main loop;

```
    for (;;) {
        ret = mnl_socket_recvfrom(nl, buf, sizeof_buf);
        if (ret == -1) {
            perror("mnl_socket_recvfrom");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ret = mnl_cb_run(buf, ret, 0, portid, queue_cb, nl);
        if (ret < 0){
            perror("mnl_cb_run");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

It has been observed that mnl_socket_recvfrom() does not return immediately when a packet is received. Up to 100ms delay has happened. To troubleshoot I use ping and tried to hog the CPU to provoke delays. But to my surprise the latency *went down* when the cpu hog was started!

```
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=120 ttl=63 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=121 ttl=63 time=1.26 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=122 ttl=63 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=123 ttl=63 time=1.26 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=124 ttl=63 time=1.24 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=125 ttl=63 time=0.627 ms <--- CPU hog started
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=126 ttl=63 time=0.334 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=127 ttl=63 time=0.628 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=128 ttl=63 time=0.599 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.0: icmp_seq=129 ttl=63 time=0.602 ms
```

Can any body explain this?

The test is made on a kvm VM with one (virtual) CPU. The nfqueue program runs with normal prio and sends verdict accept and a fwmark to forward all packets (icmp in this case). It does not matter if the CPU-hog is running with normal or nice -20 prio.

The hog is written i C, and completely dumb:

```
        unsigned long i = 0;
        for (;;) {
                i++;
        }
```

Comment: Try `cpupower frequency-set --governor performance`.

Comment: Thanks @DaBler, a very good tip! But it doesn't seem to be the cause. When I set "performance" the time without hog goes down, but with the hog it goes down even further.

Comment: Seems to be cpu frequency after all. @DaBler if you re-write your comment as an answer I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [CPUfreq governor](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt) "ondemand" sets the CPU frequency depending on the current system load. When you run a `ping` command, the CPU frequency will increase. The solution may be to set the CPU frequency to the highest frequency via this command:

```
cpupower frequency-set --governor performance
```